# Why are my Mapbox clusters flickering around while dragging the map but only on initial load?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a very basic implementation of a map (Mapbox GL) but some problems which I just cannot find out why it happens. When i first load the map and start dragging/moving the map around, the clusters are flickering around like crazy. As soon as i zoom in or out a little bit, this effect disappears.

I created a minimal test file to check what the problem could be, but can't find out what triggers that bug. It seems like a MapBox Bug itself. My research lead to this article which looks kinda similar, so i'm wondering if this is related to this bug. however i can't find a solution or a workaround.

might this be related to this bug?
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5563

here is a short video of the effect: https://recordit.co/xdENr5UOjo
here is a live URL: http://hagenhls.ch/mapbox-test.html

here is the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mapbox Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="storefinder-test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the js:

```
// get access token
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoibm9yZGthcHBlcjI4IiwiYSI6ImNqejlpMTdlejAwenkzZXM2dDF1bmxtdTMifQ.Q_XssY9aSttop553aF4zlQ';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    zoom: 9,
    center: [8.364900, 47.359438],
    projection: 'mercator',
    style: 'mapbox://mapbox/nordkapper28/clhe1mjow015r01pg4bif3fsc',
});

let geojsonData, isInitialLoad = true;

map.on('load', () => {

    // add a clustered GeoJSON source for a sample set of locations
    map.addSource('locations', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] },
        'cluster': true,
        'clusterMinPoints': 2,
        'clusterMaxZoom': 14,
        'clusterRadius': 50,
    });


    map.addLayer({
        id: 'clusters',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'locations',
        filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
        paint: {
            'circle-color': [
                'step',
                ['get', 'point_count'],
                '#51bbd6',
                100,
                '#f1f075',
                750,
                '#f28cb1'
            ],
            'circle-radius': [
                'step',
                ['get', 'point_count'],
                20,
                100,
                30,
                750,
                40
            ]
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'cluster-count',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'locations',
        filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
        layout: {
            'text-field': ['get', 'point_count_abbreviated'],
            'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-size': 12
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'unclustered-point',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'locations',
        filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
        paint: {
            'circle-color': '#11b4da',
            'circle-radius': 4,
            'circle-stroke-width': 1,
            'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
        }
    });

   
    fetchStoreLocation();

   
});


function fetchStoreLocation() {
    const sheetId = '1Dg-HDbs-4SssA4XzbxtM0FB-JDDy5_hA-CkLD3vNps0';
    const base = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${sheetId}/gviz/tq?`;
    const sheetName = 'Verkaufsstellen';
    const query = encodeURIComponent('Select *')
    const url = `${base}&sheet=${sheetName}&tq=${query}`;

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(rep => {
            //Remove additional text and extract only JSON:
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(rep.substring(47).slice(0, -2));
            //console.log(jsonData);

            let cols = jsonData.table.cols.map(entry => entry.label).filter(col => col);
            //console.log(cols);

            let data = [];

            jsonData.table.rows.map(entry => {
                // console.log(entry.c);

                let entries = entry.c.map(item => {
                    if (item) {
                        return item.f ? item.f : item.v;
                    }

                    return item;
                });

                let obj = entries.reduce((a, b, i) => {
                    a = { ...a, [cols[i]]: b };

                    return a;
                }, {});

                data.push(obj);
            });

            data = data.filter(item => item.Latitude);

            //updateCategoryOptions([...new Set(categories)]);

            let geojsonFc = createGeoJson(data)
            geojsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(geojsonFc));

            map.getSource('locations').setData(geojsonFc);
            isInitialLoad = false;
            // renderItemListing(data);

        })
        .catch(console.error)
}


function createGeoJson(data) {
    let fc = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] };

    fc.features = data.filter(item => item.Latitude).map(item => {
        let feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [parseFloat(item.Longitude), parseFloat(item.Latitude)]
            },
            "properties": { ...item }
        }

        return feature
    });

    return fc;
}
```